# Using "Show" in an interval

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have plotted two functions as below:

```
p1= LogLogPlot[RO, {t, 0.00001, 0.05}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Purple}];

p2=LogLogPlot[R1, {t, 0.00001, 0.05}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red}];
```

I then use Show to combine them:

```
Show[p2, p1]
```

My question is how can I use

> Show

so that it shows p1 and p2 only in the interval $10^{-5}<t<10^{-4}$?

I used

```
Show[p1,p2, PlotRange -> {10^(-5),10^(-4)}]
```

but the output is not in the interval $10^{-5}<t<10^{-4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show) uses the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange) setting from the first plot, you can just set your plot range when defining the first plot:

```
p1=LogLogPlot[
    RO,
    {t,0.00001,0.05},
    PlotRange -> {{10^-5, 10^-4}, All},
    PlotStyle->{Purple}
];

Show[p1, p2]
```

or you can use a dummy plot with the desired plot range:

```
p0 = LogLogPlot[None, {t, 10^-5, 10^-4}];

Show[p0, p1, p2]
```

If you really want to set the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange) using a [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show) option, than you need to realize that the [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) objects produced by `p1` and `p2` don't know that "Log" scaling functions were used. So, you need to adjust the desired [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange) accordingly:

```
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> {Log @ {10^-5, 10^-4}, All}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect, it should be

```
Show[{p1,p2},PlotRange->{{x_min,x_max},{y_min,y_max}}]
```

If you want all in y, you can do:

```
Show[{p1,p2},PlotRange->{{10^(-5),10^(-4)},All}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work.

Comment: @ZhiRuo no, because you are using a loglog plot you need to rescale the plot range as shown in the other answer. Your syntax was, however, still incorrect, as I pointed out for you.